# python: are property fields being cached automatically?

Tags: python, properties

My question is are the following two pieces of code run the same by the interpreter:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.__x = None

  @property
  def x(self):
     if not self.__x:
        self.__x = ... #some complicated action
     return self.__x
```

and the much simpler:

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def x(self):
      return ... #some complicated action
```

I.e., is the interpreter smart enough to cache the property `x`?

My assumption is that `x` does not change - finding it is *hard*, but once you find it once there is no reason to find it again.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, the getter will be called every time you access the property.

Answer (score 24):

To anyone who might be reading this in 2020, this functionality is now available in the `functools` module as part of the standard library as of Python 3.8.

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property

Important to note, classes that define their own `__dict__` (or do not define one at all) or use `__slots__` might not work as expected. For example, `NamedTuple` and metaclasses.

Answer (score 19):

No you need to add a [memoize](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) decorator:

```
class memoized(object):
   """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
   If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
   not re-evaluated.
   """
   def __init__(self, func):
      self.func = func
      self.cache = {}
   def __call__(self, *args):
      try:
         return self.cache[args]
      except KeyError:
         value = self.func(*args)
         self.cache[args] = value
         return value
      except TypeError:
         # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
         # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
         return self.func(*args)
   def __repr__(self):
      """Return the function's docstring."""
      return self.func.__doc__
   def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      """Support instance methods."""
      return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

@memoized
def fibonacci(n):
   "Return the nth fibonacci number."
   if n in (0, 1):
      return n
   return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

print fibonacci(12)
```

Comment: memoize decorator is probably overkill for a simple python property.

Comment: Also note that meanwhile, there's the [`functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator (which also permits a `maxsize=None` parameter)

Answer (score 17):

Properties do not automatically cache their return values. The getter (and setters) are intended to be called each time the property is accessed.

However, [Denis Otkidach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168352/denis-otkidach) has written a wonderful cached attribute decorator (published in [the Python Cookbook, 2nd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007973.do) and also originally on [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/276643-caching-and-aliasing-with-descriptors/) under the [PSF license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Software_Foundation_License)) for just this purpose:

```
class cache(object):    
    '''Computes attribute value and caches it in the instance.
    Python Cookbook (Denis Otkidach) https://stackoverflow.com/users/168352/denis-otkidach
    This decorator allows you to create a property which can be computed once and
    accessed many times. Sort of like memoization.

    '''
    def __init__(self, method, name=None):
        # record the unbound-method and the name
        self.method = method
        self.name = name or method.__name__
        self.__doc__ = method.__doc__
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        # self: <__main__.cache object at 0xb781340c>
        # inst: <__main__.Foo object at 0xb781348c>
        # cls: <class '__main__.Foo'>       
        if inst is None:
            # instance attribute accessed on class, return self
            # You get here if you write `Foo.bar`
            return self
        # compute, cache and return the instance's attribute value
        result = self.method(inst)
        # setattr redefines the instance's attribute so this doesn't get called again
        setattr(inst, self.name, result)
        return result
```

Here is an example demonstrating its use:

```
def demo_cache():
    class Foo(object):
        @cache
        def bar(self):
            print 'Calculating self.bar'  
            return 42
    foo=Foo()
    print(foo.bar)
    # Calculating self.bar
    # 42
    print(foo.bar)    
    # 42
    foo.bar=1
    print(foo.bar)
    # 1
    print(Foo.bar)
    # __get__ called with inst = None
    # <__main__.cache object at 0xb7709b4c>

    # Deleting `foo.bar` from `foo.__dict__` re-exposes the property defined in `Foo`.
    # Thus, calling `foo.bar` again recalculates the value again.
    del foo.bar
    print(foo.bar)
    # Calculating self.bar
    # 42

demo_cache()
```

Answer (score 15):

Python 3.2 onwards offers a built-in decorator that you can use to create a LRU cache:

[`@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Alternatively, if you're using Flask / Werkzeug, there's the [`@cached_property`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.utils.cached_property) decorator.

For Django, try `from django.utils.functional import cached_property`

Comment: Also available in Django `from django.utils.functional import cached_property`

Comment: I don't know why your answer is not upvoted more. For me, decorating a function with `@functools.lru_cache(1)` before decorating it with `@property` works wonders.

Comment: Just to clarify it for others: "decorating a function with `@functools.lru_cache(1)` before decorating it with `@property`" means that `@functools.lru_cache(1)` goes _after_ `@property` (`@functools.lru_cache(1)` closest to the function).

Answer (score 5):

I've had to look it up, since I had this same question.

The [functools package](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) from the standard library will be getting a cached_property decorator as well. Unfortunately, it's only available from Python 3.8 (as of time of this post, it's 3.8a0). The alternative to waiting is to use a custom one, such as [this one as mentioned by 0xc0de](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property)) or Django's, for now, then switch later:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
# from functools import cached_property # Only 3.8+ :(
```

Comment: You can stack `@property` and `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize)`, you know. And `@functools.lru_cache` is available since Python 3.2

Answer (score 3):

The decorator from Denis Otkidach mentioned in @unutbu's answer was published in O'Reilly's Python Cookbook. Unfortunately O'Reilly doesn't specify any license for code examples – just as informal permission to reuse the code.

If you need a cached property decorator with a liberal license, you can use [Ken Seehof](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/users/4167995/)'s `@cached_property` from [ActiveState code recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576563-cached-property/). It's explicitly published under the [MIT license](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/tags/meta%3alicense=mit/).

```
def cached_property(f):
    """returns a cached property that is calculated by function f"""
    def get(self):
        try:
            return self._property_cache[f]
        except AttributeError:
            self._property_cache = {}
            x = self._property_cache[f] = f(self)
            return x
        except KeyError:
            x = self._property_cache[f] = f(self)
            return x

    return property(get)
```

Comment: Additionally, if you are working on a Django project you can import `@cached_property` from `django.utils.functional`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Adding for the sake of completeness of available options.

No, `property` is not cached by default. However there are several options to get that behaviour, I would like to add one more to that:

https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property