# Computed static property in python

Tags: python, static-methods

Is it possible to have a static property on a class that would be computed as a one off. The idea would be to be able to do it like so:

```
class Foo:
    static_prop = Foo.one_off_static_method()

    @staticmethod
    def one_off_static_method():
        return 'bar'
```

I thought of using `__new__` as well.

```
Class Foo:
    def __new__(cls):
         cls.static_prop = ... do everything here
```

Not sure the implications of that though.

Comment: Do you want this lazily evaluated (and is it actually something sufficiently expensive and sufficiently likely to never be used that lazy evaluation makes sense)?

Comment: Did you try making a staticmethod a property?

Comment: Do you want it computed at first-use or at class definition time?

Comment: This is what I use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849299/107660

Comment: @user2357112 It is expensive, a file gets opened read and a data structure is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it computed at class definition time, see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498950/674039) - although I would recommend just to use a module level function instead.

If you want it lazily evaluated, per instance, then you might be interested in [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html?highlight=s#functools.cached_property).

```
>>> from random import random
>>> from functools import cached_property
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @cached_property
...     def one_off_thing(self):
...         print("computing...")
...         return random()
...     
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.one_off_thing
computing...
0.5804382038855782
>>> foo.one_off_thing
0.5804382038855782
```

*Note:* stdlib `functools.cached_property` requires Python 3.8+, for Python < 3.8 you can [`pip install cached_property`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property/).

Comment: This would be computed once per instance though right?

Comment: Yes, once per instance.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, I made a small descriptor for you :-)

Upon accessing the attribute, it will be computed and cached.

```
class CachedStaticProperty:
    """Works like @property and @staticmethod combined"""

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, inst, owner):
        result = self.func()
        setattr(owner, self.func.__name__, result)
        return result
```

The way it works is rather simple:

1. Upon using the decorator syntax, I save the function internally.
2. Upon access, I call the function and set the value as the class value with the same name as the original function.

That's all there is to it. Simple and efficient.

Comment: @mkohram Whoops, here you go :-)
It's even smaller :P

Comment: @mkohram Added a small explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Until the class is actually created, `one_off_static_method` is just a regular function. It needs to be defined before you attempt to call it, since you want to call it while the `class` statement is being executed. Once you are done with it, you can simply delete it.

```
class Foo:
    def _one_off_static_method():
        return 'bar'

    static_prop = _one_off_static_method()
    del _one_off_static_method
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Python 3.8 there will be a `cached_property` decorator included in the Python builtin/core `functools` library.

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html?highlight=s#functools.cached_property

Other questions on this website have similar answers. Some highlights are that one can do

```
@property
@functools.lru_cache(1)
```

(both Python builtins) for a similar effect. And that some web server libraries like Flask or Werkzeug already include their own implementations of `cached_property` decorators.

There are of course other ways (as mentioned in the other answers to this question and the answers to other questions) that one can create their own custom cached property decorators.

[python: are property fields being cached automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428723/python-are-property-fields-being-cached-automatically)
[Is there a decorator to simply cache function return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values)